# java joption and convert string to integer

Tags: java

I am not quite sure what i am doing wrong with this code.

I am trying to import the joptionpane and then convert the string into an int
my error comes at

```
**start = inputValue.Integer.parseInt();**
 JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();

String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a value"); 
start = inputValue.Integer.parseInt();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`start = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant `start = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);`